# Direct limits of injective modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Is it true that the direct limit of injective modules is injective?

Comment: See page 81 Theorem 3.46 Lectures on Modules and Rings by Lam. This has exactly the theorem refered to in the comment below and is a nice textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over what ring?

In particular, the answer to your question is "yes" iff the ring is [Noetherian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring).

Comment: To be clearer: the answer is yes for all direct limits of injective module if and only if the ring is noetherian.